# Scala : XML Parsing - Obtain parent tag which contains a value as part of its child

Tags: scala, xml-parsing

**Input**

```
<Groups>
<Group>
    <Service name="A" enable="0"/>
    <Service name="B" enable="1"/>
    <NodeSet>
        <Node ip="abd"/>
    </NodeSet>
</Group>

<Group>
    <Service name="E" enable="0"/>
    <Service name="F" enable="1"/>
    <NodeSet>
        <Node ip="mno"/>
    </NodeSet>
</Group>

</Groups>
```

I have provided a very simplified version of the XML file, which we are using.

**Question**
I want to have a list of services which matches a given IP. So in this case, I would like to get Service `A` and `B` for the IP `abd`.

I am aware of XPath, which will help me identify the IP if present. However, I would not be able to find the service names, once I find the IP (is present). Could you please guide me to a good source which can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually are after are the `Group` nodes that have the specified ip under them. Get them first, then you can iterate through them to get the `Service` names from under them. Iterating and parsing XML trees is pretty straightforward with the basic list operations once you have parsed the XML into memory:

```
val xml = XML.loadFile("file")
val matchingGroups = (xml \\ "Group").filter(n => (n \ "NodeSet" \ "Node" \ "@ip").text == "abd")
val serviceNames = matchingGroups.flatMap(n => n \ "Service").map(n => (n \ "@name").text)
```

Might need some revision depending on the exact XML schema - attribute traversal works only on single nodes and not sequences.